# Functors in OCaml: triple code duplication necessary?

Tags: ocaml, functor

I'd like to clarify one point: currently it seems to me that triple signature duplication is necessary while declaring a functor, provided we export it in the .mli file. Here is an example:

Suppose we have a functor `Make`, which produces a module `A` parametrized by `SigA` (simplest example I could think of). Consequently, in the .mli file we have:

```
module type A = sig
    type a
    val identity : a -> a
end

module type SigA = sig
    type a
end

module Make (MA:SigA) :
    A with type a := MA.a
```

Now I understand that we have to write an implementation in the .ml file:

```
module Make (MA:SigA) = struct
    type a = MA.a

    let identity obj = obj
end
```

So far so good, right? No! Turns out we have to copy the declaration of `A` and `SigA` verbatim into the .ml file:

```
module type A = sig
    type a

    val identity : a -> a
end

module type SigA = sig
    type a
end

module Make (MA:SigA) = struct
    type a = MA.a

    let identity obj = obj
end
```

While I (vaguely) understand the rationale behind copying `SigA` (after all, it is mentioned in the source code), copying `A` definition seems like a completely pointless exercise to me.
I've had a brief look through the Core codebase, and they just seem to either duplicate it for small modules and for larger once they export it to the separate .mli, which is used both from .ml and .mli.

So is it just a state of affairs? Is everyone fine with copying the module signature THREE times (once in the .mli file, two times in the .ml file: declaration and the definition!!)
Currently I'm considering just ditching .mli files altogether and restricting the modules export using signatures in the .ml files.

---

EDIT: yes I know that I can avoid this problem by declaring the interface for `A` inline inside `Make` in the .mli file. However this doesn't help me if I want to use that interface from outside of that module.

Comment: I am not the most familiar with this OCaml feature, but I think it would be worth your time looking at the newly-introduced `module type of` construct. The very problem you describe used to plague the Frama-C source code as long as it was maintaing compatibility with OCaml < 3.12, but now that Frama-C has switched to 3.12.1 or higher, the source code is greatly simplified by the use of this feature.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks! I know the construct, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use it to avoid the repetition =( Any pointers would be highly appreciated! [ah I guess I might just look at their source code]

Comment: @PascalCuoq one solution I can think of is to define the functor signature inline in `sig .. end`, and then for the _users_ of the module obtain the signature by using `module type of Make(...)`. 
I've had a (very brief) look at the Frama-C codebase --- it seems that they define functors "inline" mostly.
However such an approach makes it impossible to obtain a signature for an abstract, non-parametrized module type (though I'm not sure whether it is a good thing)

Comment: @PascalCuoq src/lib/hptset.ml still has such a duplication.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I don't see how `module type of` helps here, other than perhaps removing the nested module type name in the separate file solution (though what I'm thinking of is rather a hack I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: @AndreasRossberg I think I've figured it out --- one can define functor inline inside `module Make (...) (...) : sig ... end`, without a spurious `S` signature. Then, when one needs a signature of the functor output they can do `module MyModule : module type of Make(...)(...)`. I've just applied it to my codebase and everything looks oh-so-much-better.

Comment: @cheshire Frama-C Neon was released today. It contains many instances of `module type of` that, as I remember, are mostly useful to get rid of interfaces that were inconveniently duplicated in previous Frama-C versions. http://frama-c.com/download.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because a pair of ML and MLI file acts like a structure and a corresponding signature it is matched against.

The usual way to avoid writing out the module type twice is to define it in a separate ML file. For example,

```
(* sig.ml *)
module type A = sig
  type a
end

module type B = sig
  type b
  val identity : b -> b
end

(* make.mli *)
module Make (A : Sig.A) : Sig.B with type b = A.a

(* make.ml *)
module Make (A : Sig.A) =
struct
  type b = A.a
  let identity x = x
end
```

It is fine to leave out an MLI file in the case where it does not hide anything, like for the `Sig` module above.

In other cases, writing out the signature separately from the implementation is a feature, and not really duplication -- it defines the export of a module, and usually, that is a small subset of what's in the implementation.

Comment: thanks --- I've already mentioned it in my question though: "and they just seem to either duplicate it for small modules and for larger once they export it to the separate .mli, which is used both from .ml and .mli". Repeating the declaration three times, or using 3 files where 2 suffices does look like a shortcoming IMO.

Comment: "separate .mli" does not work, though, it has to be an .ml file. That's why I wasn't sure you meant the same thing. FWIW, I still disagree about the 3 times, but I agree that 2 times is one too many. I don't see extra files as a serious issue, though.

Comment: Oh, right, thanks, but yes, that's what I've meant (thanks for correcting the mistake though).

Comment: 2 times, OK, sure (though I am writing the signatures of publicly exported functions twice)

Comment: But you are not usually writing down their signatures in the implementation.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg A separate standalone ".mli" does work, as long as there are no value components in it.